# Jquery zoom image with image map

Tags: jquery, zooming, imagemap

I would like to implement image map along with zoom using jquery . Is there any way to do that ? .. couldn't find any tutorial/example to have them both.
Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [these examples](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html). You can download them an try to reverse engineer it the way you need. Then perhaps once you get started on something, people here can give your more advice to complete it